Error with Java Google Cloud Helloworld deployment
Aim
I'm new to Google Cloud and working towards setting up Java IntelliJ with Google Cloud.
After running:
gcloud run deploy 

Error information:
IntelliJ throws:
Building using Buildpacks and deploying container to Cloud Run service [helloworld] in project [first-project-himanshu] region [us-central1]
X  Building and deploying new service... Building Container.                                                                                                                                                   
  OK Uploading sources...                                                                                                                                                                                      
  -  Building Container... Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/01c579f3-ff0e-438c-8677-c9fe3904f031?project=734796074243].                                              
  .  Creating Revision...                                                                                                                                                                                      
  .  Routing traffic...                                                                                                                                                                                        
  .  Setting IAM Policy...                                                                                                                                                                                     
Deployment failed                                                                                                                                                                                              
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Build failed; check build logs for details


Logs on Google Cloud show:
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 51
[builder] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[builder] Timer: Builder ran for 17.519306196s and ended at 2024-04-04T21:46:25Z
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder]  -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/new
[builder] If you think you've found an issue, please report it:
[builder]  -> https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/overview
[builder] Our documentation explains ways to configure Buildpacks to better recognise your project:
[builder] Sorry your project couldn't be built.
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[builder] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[builder] [ERROR] 
[builder] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[builder] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[builder] [ERROR] 
[builder] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project helloworld: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
[builder] Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
[builder] failed to build: (error ID: dc066188):
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] Done "./mvnw clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests -Dhttp.keepAli..." (11.891255152s)
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] 
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] 
[builder] 
[builder] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project helloworld: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
[builder] Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
[builder] Running "./mvnw clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests -Dhttp.keepAlive=false -f=pom.xml --quiet"
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] === Java - Maven (google.java.maven@0.9.0) ===
[builder] 2024/04/04 21:46:08 [DEBUG] GET https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu2204/openjdk/openjdk-11.0.22_7.tar.gz
[builder] Installing  v11.0.22+7.
[builder] ***** CACHE MISS: "openjdk"
[builder] 2024/04/04 21:46:07 [DEBUG] GET https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu2204/openjdk/version.json
[builder] Using latest Java 11 runtime version. You can specify a different version with GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks#configuration
[builder] === Java - Runtime (google.java.runtime@0.9.2) ===
===> BUILDING
[restorer] Timer: Restorer ran for 640.4µs and ended at 2024-04-04T21:46:06Z
[restorer] Timer: Restorer started at 2024-04-04T21:46:06Z
===> RESTORING
[detector] Timer: Detector ran for 148.746086ms and ended at 2024-04-04T21:46:06Z
[detector] google.utils.label-image 0.0.2
[detector] google.java.entrypoint   0.9.0
[detector] google.java.maven        0.9.0
[detector] google.java.runtime      0.9.2
[detector] 4 of 5 buildpacks participating
[detector] Timer: Detector started at 2024-04-04T21:46:06Z
===> DETECTING

Attempted fix:
Can't seem to get to the bottom of this. I did review:

Permissions on Google cloud
Maven configuration (might be missing something here)
Went through these GCould documentation - link

Goal
To run Helloworld deployment via IntelliJ Community into Google Cloud by running gcloud run deploy on IntelliJ

Hi there,
Can you try to build the same image locally and see if it works?
This caught my eye on your logs
Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported
Is it possible to change whatever that release version package in Java you are using to a minor or other version?
Regards

Based on the error ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 51 [builder] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1, I think this is more on the configuration of Maven than in GCP. I see three possible common issues:
First, check the correct version of your JDK, you may follow the steps below (blockquote won't format) [1]:

Settings / Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools
-> Maven -> Importing
Settings / Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools
-> Maven -> Runner
Settings / Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler ->
Java Compiler -> Project bytecode version
Project Structure -> Project -> SDK / Language Level
Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources -> Language level Project
Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Module SDK

Make sure you're also a proper JDK and not a JRE, which solved the OP's issue.
Next, make sure you're not running Maven as a sudo, since JAVA_HOME is getting overriden[2].
Lastly, check your pom.xml file and explicitly reference the Java version:
<configuration>
<image>
    <name>${project.groupId}/payment.service:${project.version}</name>
    <env>
        <BP_JVM_VERSION>${java.version}</BP_JVM_VERSION>
    </env>
</image>
</configuration>

You may view the full discussion in this Stack Overflow thread.

[1]. Fatal error compiling: release version 17 not supported
[2]. maven-comiler-plugin: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported
